# How to use Group by and Having count clause in entity framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I'm new to `entity framework` and I'm trying to convert an `SQL` query to `entity framework`. But I'm not able to convert the `having` clause.

SQL query is:

```
select tblRecordingType_ID
from tblEquipmentReadingTypes
group by tblRecordingType_ID
having count(tblRecordingType_ID) > 0
```

I have written following `EF` query:

```
 var items = from o in context.tblEquipmentReadingTypes                            
                        group o by o.tblRecordingType_ID
```

Please let me know, how i can use `having` clause with this.

Thanks

Comment: [This article](http://devkimchi.com/211/playing-group-by-and-having-clauses-with-linq/) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
select tblRecordingType_ID
from tblEquipmentReadingTypes
group by tblRecordingType_ID
having count(tblRecordingType_ID) > 0
```

is equivalent to this:

```
select tblRecordingType_ID
from tblEquipmentReadingTypes
where tblRecordingType_ID is not null
group by tblRecordingType_ID
```

So you can just write something like this in `linq`:

```
var items = from o in context.tblEquipmentReadingTypes 
            where o.tblRecordingType_ID != null                           
            group o by o.tblRecordingType_ID into grouped
            select grouped.Key
```

Comment: It's not really equivalent :( what if they wanted count > 1? The fact that for this specific case (count > 0) your solution would provide the same result, doesn't mean they are equivalent.

Answer (score 16):

you can use `where` after `group by` and using `into` statment:

```
var items = from o in context.tblEquipmentReadingTypes
            group o by o.tblRecordingType_ID into g
            where g.Count() > 0
            select g;
```

Comment: This is the equivalent of `group by` and `having count > x` clauses combined, and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I agree with  – Alisson. This should be the accepted answer